# Images on listing page not as clear as in description page

Tags: product-images

The images on the **listing page** are not clear but in the product description page are clear. **What can be done to improve clarity?**

The listing page images are smaller in size to the description page. we uploaded images with water mark in `1100*1100` specification.

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Fixed size images as per your layout.

You can resize image with fixed height and variable width. Or, you can resize with fixed width and variable height. Following code shows how you do it in Magento.

> For product image on list page, navigate to `app\design\frontend\[your
>   package]\[your theme]\template\catalog\product\list.phtml`, and look
>   for the line where image is being called.

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
   ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
   ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
   ->keepFrame(FALSE)
   ->resize(400,400)
?>
```

**constrainOnly(bool $flag)**

it is used make sure that image picture will not be bigger, than it was. Applicable before calling resize() It is false by default.

**keepAspectRatio(bool $flag)**

it is used make sure that image picture width/height will not be distorted. Applicable before calling resize() It is true by default.

**keepFrame(bool $flag)**

it is used make sure that image will have dimensions, set in $width/$height. Applicable before calling resize() Not applicable, if keepAspectRatio(false).

**EDIT**

You can also use magento's method for quality set for images `setQuality(100)`

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
       ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
       ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
       ->keepFrame(FALSE)
       ->resize(400,400)
       ->setQuality(100)
?>
```

For more info about magento image functions see the [source](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-resize-image/)